# Yii2 create large amount of data

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have to create a large amount of data from an existing table data. The amount is about 5000 to 10000 data a day.

My controller:

```
$skus = Sku3d::find()->all();

foreach ($skus as $sku) {
    $model = new Loghour3d();
    $model->sku = $sku->sku;
    $model->modeler = $sku->modeler;
    $model->team = $sku->team;
    $time = new \DateTime('now');
    $today = $time->format('Y-m-d');
    $model->day = $today;
    $model->handover = $sku->handover;
    $model->hour = $sku->totalhours;
    $model->save();
}
```

But the hours created is not correct. Example: `$sku->totalhours = 12` but `$model->hour = 600` and my code is `$model->hour = $sku->totalhours;`. So I don't know where `600` from.

And also is there a better way to complete this task, because right now it takes about 15-20 minutes.

Comment: About 12-600 - there's alot of things, which can cause this happens. Try to dump `$model->hour` and `$model->totalhours` right before `$model->save()`, check model rules. About optimization, right now you fire 5-10k queries one-by-one. With big datasets, it's better to leave `ActiveRecord` and prepare direct queries, and even better - one bigger query. Fetch data to array, prepare datasets and fire one query at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to speed up processing of large amount of data from database, you should resign from using `ActiveRecord` in the first place. Operating on arrays and using [DAO](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-dao) should be much more efficient than creating `ActiveRecord` object for each record.

Second - you should use [`batchInsert()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-command#batchInsert()-detail) to insert multiple records in one query. Inserting 100 records in one query is faster than doing it in 100 separate queries.

Third - if some value is the same for each record, move it before foreach. There is no point of calculating current date 10000 times if it is always the same.

```
$skus = Sku3d::find()->asArray()->all();
$time = new \DateTime('now');
$today = $time->format('Y-m-d');

$toInsert = [];
foreach ($skus as $sku) {
    $toInsert[] = [
        'sku' => $sku['sku'],
        'modeler' => $sku['modeler'],
        'team' => $sku['team'],
        'day' => $today,
        'handover' => $sku['handover'],
        'hour' => $sku['totalhours'],
    ];
}

Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
    ->batchInsert(
        Loghour3d::tableName(),
        [
            'sku',
            'modeler',
            'team',
            'day',
            'handover',
            'hour',
        ],
        $toInsert
    )
    ->execute();
```

Comment: Hi @rob006, thank you for your help :) just a question can I use math inside `toInsert[]`? Ex: `hour => $sku['totalhours'] - $sku['oldtotalhours']`

Comment: @SaoHo Sure, it should not have big impact on performance. The bottleneck here was the creation of `ActiveRecord` objects and the SQL queries.